# MongoDb: sort text search results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I've created a query which returns results that contain 
`"Be"` inside the field value. e.g.:

```
db.collection.find({ "$or" : [ { "name.en" : { "$regex" : "Be" } } , { "defaultName" : { "$regex" : "Be" } } ] })
```

However, the returned results are sorted in random way, some contain `"Be"` inside the word, some in the beginning, some in the end.

Is it possible to create a single query which would sort results the following way: first returned results will start with `"Be"` and then will be all the rest?

Query results example:

```
{
"defaultName" : "Belgium",
...
},
{
"defaultName" : "Berlin",
...
},
{
"defaultName" : "Bombei",
...
},
{
"defaultName" : "Danube",
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

such approach could be done using aggreagtion framework

stages will be:

> 1. Match - select elements matching regex
> 2. Group elements by expression if starts with regex phrase -> true, else false
> 3. sort by expression from 2

What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like a working solution. Unfortunately I doesn't see another solution than using aggregation framework for now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's my pleasure :-)